# Is it possible to detect key type with json_encode?

Tags: php, json

Quite a difficult to explain, but for example i have an array:

```
$lol = array(
    'key' => 'value',
    'key_1' => 'value 1',
    'simple_value',
    '0' => 'lol',
    'key_array' => array(
        'key_in_second' => 'value_with_key_in_second',
        'value_in_second_array',
    )
);
```

After `json_encode` it would be

```
{"key":"value","key_1":"value 1","0":"lol","key_array":{"key_in_second":"value_with_key_in_second","0":"value_in_second_array"}}
```

So is it possible somehow detect if in `php` array had the key or note? In my example elements `'simple_value', '0' => 'lol'` have same key.

Comment: Detecting the type. As the array you have shown, everything is wrapped with quotes, so PHP will read it as strings, thus transmit to json as a string.

Comment: @DarylGill you do not understand, i need to know if array in in `php` had key or not.

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't care if the number 0 is in quotes or not.  It is storing it as numeric 0, same as 'value_in_second_array' will be 0, as it was the first element without a key.

Basically,

`array('0'=>'lol')` is the same as `array(0=>'lol')` is the same is `array('lol')`;

You'll see simple_value dissappeared, as it was overwritten with lol.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON accurately reflects the php.  For example, if you had this code:

```
<?php
$lol = array(
    'key' => 'value',
    'key_1' => 'value 1',
    'simple_value',
    '0' => 'lol',
    'key_array' => array(
        'key_in_second' => 'value_with_key_in_second',
        'value_in_second_array',
    )
);

print_r($lol);
```

The output would be:

```
Array
(
    [key] => value
    [key_1] => value 1
    [0] => lol
    [key_array] => Array
        (
            [key_in_second] => value_with_key_in_second
            [0] => value_in_second_array
        )

)
```

What happened here is that as `simple_value` didn't have a key, it was assigned a key of 0, but was then overwritten with `lol` which came next.  You can also see how the `value_in_second_array` was automatically assigned a key of 0.

So, nothing to do with `json_encode`, you just never had the data in PHP.